# How do I remove a View in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am still quite new to react and till now I am still not able to understand how to remove a View when the user clicks on a specific button.
For example lets say I have this block of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, View, Text, TouchAbleOpacity } from 'react-native'

class Example extends Component {
    removeView(){
        // what should I do here?
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <View> // View to be removed
                    <TouchAbleOpacity onPress={() => this.removeView()}>
                      <Text>Remove View</Text>
                    </TouchAbleOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('example', () => Example);
```

How do I programmatically remove the View element?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        showView: true,
      }
    }

    removeView(){
       this.setState({
         showView: false,
       });
    }

    render(){
        return (
           <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
           {this.state.showView && (
                <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100 }}> // View to be removed
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.removeView()}>
                      <Text>Remove View</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
           )}
           </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How it will work for multiple `View` and `TouchableHighlight`? state is for common!

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, View, Text, TouchAbleOpacity } from 'react-native'

class Example extends Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        showView:true
      }
    }

    removeView(){
        this.setState({
          showView:false
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                {this.renderView()}
            </View>
        )
    }

    renderView(){
      if(this.state.showView){
        return(
          <View>
              <TouchAbleOpacity onPress={() => this.removeView()}>
                <Text>Remove View</Text>
              </TouchAbleOpacity>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('example', () => Example);
```

Comment: Is it 100% removed though? Or is it like adding a "hide class into a div"? also, will it work for multiple views?

Comment: Yes the View gets unmounted and yes you can do this for multiple views.

Comment: You're basically showing all the views if `showView` is set to true, so when the user clicks on the button wouldn't that remove all of the views?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question with the multiple views. That is a good question by the way. I will need to think how I will do that never had to do it like that before.

Comment: @Alex, I ran into the same problem today. I had to remove buttons. So I created a new  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106378/remove-multiple-components-without-using-the-state) on how to remove multiple components.